# Modify dataGrouping in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Highcharts hour data aggregation flow 
follows the next rules: `01 AM = 01:00 + 01:15 + 01:30 + 01:45`. (example). So all points between current hour and the next one.
I want it to follow the rule: `01 AM = 00:00 + 00:15 + 00:30 + 00:45`

I didn't find a possibility to do that in datagrouping options of library.
Now I'm thinking about hack to modify `serie.groupedData` object (adding 1 hour to time present there), but unfortunately, even though data is modified it still display old values in chart

```
    chartConfiguration.xAxis[0].events = {
        setExtremes(event) {
            this.series.forEach(serie => {
                if (serie.hasGroupedData && serie.currentDataGrouping.unitName == "hour") {
                    let groupedData = serie.groupedData.map(dataPiece => {
                        dataPiece.x = dataPiece.x + 3600000;
                        return dataPiece;
                    });
                    serie.update(groupedData);
                }
            })  
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This code changes `x` value of all the points to one hour earlier if 1 hour data grouping is applied:

```
   chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {
        if (redrawEnabled) { // prevent infinte recursive loop - this.redraw() calls render event
          redrawEnabled = false;

          var series = this.series[0],
            isHourUnit = series.currentDataGrouping.unitName === 'hour';

          if (isHourUnit && !hourOffsetApplied) {
            // change the data
            series.setData(data.slice().map((p) => [p[0] - hour, p[1]]), false);
            hourOffsetApplied = true;
          } else if (!isHourUnit && hourOffsetApplied) {
            // resotre the original data
            series.setData(data, false);
            hourOffsetApplied = false;
          }

          this.redraw();
          redrawEnabled = true;
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z850035n/

If you change `dataGrouping.units` to `['day', [1]]` point are displayed without time offset.